# Java, passing an object to a different class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

I am new to java and am trying to understand object oriented programming.

I am trying to store an object in an array. However the array is located in a different class from the original object. I get a compiler error "Incompatible types" required (1 class) found (another class).

Please take a look at my code and let me know what I am doing wrong.

This is from class "Cluster" and this method is supposed to store an object from class "FeatureVector" into an array called "featureV".

```
 public boolean add (FeatureVector examples){
    int currentPosition;

    if (this.getSize()==this.featureV.length){
      return false;
    }
    else 
      currentPosition=this.getSize();
    featureV[currentPosition+1]=examples;
    return true;
```

EDIT:

this is the way Cluster is defined as well as featureV:

```
class Cluster{
  private Cluster [] featureV;


Cluster(int capacity){
  Cluster [] featureV= new Cluster [capacity];
```

Error:

Error: incompatible types
  required: Cluster
  found:    FeatureVector

If it helps, here is the requirement and the output that I am supposed to achieve:

```
Cluster c;  
c = new Cluster(10);  
c.add(new FeatureVector("A", new double[] { 0.0, 0.0 }));  
c.add(new FeatureVector("B", new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 }));  
c.add(new FeatureVector("C", new double[] { 1.0, 0.0 }));  
c.add(new FeatureVector("D", new double[] { 2.0, 0.0 }));  
FeatureVector.setVerbose(true);  
System.out.println(c);
```

The above statements will display the following on the console:

```
Cluster: {A: {0.0, 0.0}, B: {1.0, 1.0}, C: {1.0, 0.0}, D: {2.0, 0.0}}
```

If more information is needed please let me know.

Thank you so much! This forum is a revelation. :)

Comment: How is `featureV` declared?

Comment: Please post the exact error you get, and point to the place in the source code this error refers to. Also show how the types are declared, e.g. what is `featureV` ?

Comment: Have a think about your object model. It doesn't make much sense for a Cluster object to contain an array of Cluster objects. What is it a cluster *of?*

Comment: The idea here is that class FeatureVector contains a large number of instances (examples of data), the Cluster class is to hold a number of groups (or clusters) of data from the FeatureVector collections.

Say:

I have 40 objects in FeatureVector
But i want to have it grouped in 5 objects. So i will have 5 cluster instances storing 8 objects from FeatureVector

Comment: So Cluster contains an array of FeatureVector, and FeatureVector contains ...?

Comment: Each Feature Vector contains objects with 2 types of data: 1 string, 1 array of double values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In add(FeatureVector examples) you store an Object of the Class FeatureVector in the array featureV

```
public boolean add (FeatureVector examples){
  [...]
  featureV[currentPosition+1]=examples;
  [...]
}
```

For this to work featureV would have to be of the class FeatureVector[] or a superclass of FeatureVector[].

But when declaring the variable featureV in your second snippet, you declare it as Cluster[]

```
class Cluster{
  private Cluster [] featureV;
```

Unless FeatureVector extends Cluster (which would probably make no sense in this context) featureV is of the wrong type to fit FeatureVector.
You need to change the type of featureV to FeatureVector[]

```
class Cluster{
  private FeatureVector [] featureV;
```

To explain that a bit simpler, lets change the class types and variable names to something else:

```
class FruitBasket {
  private FruitBasket [] fruits;

  public boolean add (Fruit examples){
    fruits[currentPosition+1]=examples;
  }
}
```

So now we have a class FruitBasket, where each Object of the class FruitBasket contains an array of FruitBaskets. So we have a certain amount of slots where FruitBaskets can be fitted.
Now in your add-method you take Fruits and try to squeeze them into the FruitBasket-slots.
Can you see why this doesn't work?
You can only cast compatible objects from one to another. So while you could use either an apple or an orange when it says Fruits, you cannot use a fruit, when it says FruitBaskets.

So what you do is this:

```
class FruitBasket {
  private Fruit [] fruits;

  public boolean add (Fruit examples){
    fruits[currentPosition+1]=examples;
  }
}
```

This is probably what you intended. This FruitBasket now has a certain amount of slots for Fruits, and now you can use the add()-method to add another fruit to the basket.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply. This has been very helpful. I just have a question. If I am declaring an array fruits under Fruit class, why would I need FruitBasket class? The idea of classes is to protect information and make it private to  the they are in. If I follow the example you provided above, would my fruits belong to FruitBasket or to Fruit in terms of data protection? The line "private Fruit [] fruits;" makes it private within FruitBasket or within Fruit?

Thank you again. You have been extremely helpful.

Comment: Data protection is not the most important part of classes. Classes are more about packing things together that belong together.

For your example: Would it make sense, that a Fruit consists of multiple Fruits? If so, go ahead, if not, pack the Fruit-Array into a different class, that consists of/contains Fruits.

For your second question: you have to distinguish between Objects and References. An object is a certain representation of data in the memory. A Reference is a variable pointing to that object.
The reference fruits will be visible only to FruitBasket, the Object will be visible to all

Comment: So if you give two different objects references to the same fruit, both will be able to access the fruit.
Example:
Fruit apple = new Fruit();
FruitBasket basketA = new FruitBasket();
FruitBasket basketB = new FruitBasket();
basketA.add(apple);
basketB.add(apple);

Now the apple will be in the Fruit[] fruits-Array of both baskets. Both baskets will be able to access the apple.

But the reference private Fruit[] fruits will not be accessible from other classes (from the outside FruitBasket.fruits[0] = apple; will not work)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class Cluster{
  private FeatureVector [] featureV;


Cluster(int capacity){
  FeatureVector [] featureV= new FeatureVector [capacity];
```

You are defining an array of Objects of a certain type (here: Cluster) and you want to store another object in this array; this incompatible. You have to define the array of the Class you want to store objects of in it.

Comment: The above example may work but it the new objects are defined under FeatureVector while I need them to be under Cluster. Since in my original code I am trying to store references of FeatureVector in Cluster, it does not make sense. However If i had a way of properly copying the objects' data from FeatureVector and creating a completely new object under Cluster, it might work, but I do not know how to do that, or if it is even possible.

Comment: The above example appears to be correct. Your comment is incomprehensible.

Comment: Consider restructuring your classes, probably you should make yourself familiar with inheritance of objects and reflection.

Comment: Why reflection? It's a straightforward data model problem. I don't even see any requirement for inheritance here, unless maybe FeatureVector inherits from some vector class, in which case more probably it should just *be* a vector class, e.g. ArrayList<Feature>.

Comment: no vector class, no ArrayList.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have an array of an object within it's own class: `class Cluster{
  private Cluster [] featureV;`. If The OP wants to have a "cluster of cluster objects" which then are actually FeatureVectors, he could either inherit FeatureVector from Cluster (I don't know the purpose of that all) or make a generic ArrayList within Cluster. In order to prevent endless casting and have this almost typesafe, my first thought was Reflection. But I may be wrong.